# Suggestions for navigating a json object graph

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looking for alternative ways to parse a JSON tree. Given the following example:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  }
}
```

if I am trying to access branches, such as `address.streetAddress` or `address.city` then I can see two ways of getting that value:

1) JSON Path with the queries listed above

2) Manually split the query into "branches" (main branch address, sub-branch streetAddress) then check the object keys that way.

---

Are there any better ways of doing this? And by better I mean efficient, not necessarily "clean" in terms of code.

The application of said code would be to use this within an NGRX metareducer to automatically save the object to localstorage, so it is potentially going to be evaluating a large tree very often.

Thanks.

---

After some testing of various methods I ended up selecting _ug's answer.

Data below, as well as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/DinoSourcesRex/72ebc9a881878254901c610fc0854747) of the script I used (sans data, which was sensitive). I ran each function 1 million times over 4 queries.

```
Executing test: empty test
Average time for 1,000,000 executions: 6.181699991226196 milliseconds.

Executing test: split and reduce
Average time for 1,000,000 executions: 429.71359902620316 milliseconds.

Executing test: lodash
Average time for 1,000,000 executions: 1091.8809990286827 milliseconds.

Executing test: json path
Average time for 1,000,000 executions: 32114.680999994278 milliseconds.
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for different ways of navigating an object graph, rather than anything to do with parsing JSON, which is just text.

Comment: Poorly named @HereticMonkey, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally just wrote something for this, it doesn't work for arrays but is very simple.

```js
let obj = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  }
}

function jsonPath(path, obj) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((o, p) => o[p], obj);
}

console.log(jsonPath('address.streetAddress', obj));
console.log(jsonPath('address.city', obj));
```

You could also adapt it to run with arrays by changing the split to handle brackets `split(/[\[\.\]]+/)`

You can also make it return undefined instead of throwing an error when a path value is not found by changing the reduce to `reduce((o, p) => o && o[p], obj)`

Result would be:

```js
let obj = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "addresses"  : [{
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  }]
}

function jsonPath(path, obj) {
  return path.split(/[\[\.\]]+/).reduce((o, p) => o && o[p], obj);
}

console.log(jsonPath('addresses[0].streetAddress', obj));
console.log(jsonPath('addresses[0].city', obj));
console.log(jsonPath('addresses[2].city', obj));
```

Comment: That falls into the #2 category, for sure. I'm likely going to run some tests against this before I approve it as the accepted answer so that I can pick what performs best. I appreciate great, and quick, response.

Comment: Congratulations! This one performed the best by far, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash `_.property` method to do so:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#property

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let obj = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  }
}

console.log(_.property('address.streetAddress')(obj));

// Or

console.log(_.propertyOf(obj)('address.streetAddress'));
```